# Compare 2 columns and count how many times the team won in ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, case

I have a such table which already joined some tables. It's about basketball games. I want to get a result which shows team name and the number of games, and how many games a team won and lose.

GAME table:

```
game_id - NUMBER<br>
game_date - DATE<br>
location - VARCHAR2<br>
home_teamName - VARCHAR2<br>
away_teamName - VARCHAR2<br>
home_point - NUMBER<br>
away_point - NUMBER<br>
```

Desired result:

```
team_name - VARCHAR2<br>
games - NUMBER<br>
win - NUMBER<br>
lose - NUMBER<br>
```

like this:

name|games|win|lose
AAA |   10   | 8 |2
BBB |   9     | 4 |4
CCC |   10   | 6 |5

For now, I managed to get the number of games each team had, using code below, but I have no idea to get the others. I'm also wondering whether I can get everything without joining tables or not.

```
SELECT T1.NAME, COUNT(T1.NAME) "GAME"
FROM SEE_GAME G
JOIN TEAM T1 ON G.HOME = T1.NAME
RIGHT JOIN TEAM T2 ON G.AWAY = T2.NAME
WHERE "HOME POINT" IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY T1.NAME;
```

result from the code above: 
name|GAME
AAA |    10
BBB |     9
CCC |    10
DDD |    10

TEAM table:
team_id - NUMBER
name - VARCHAR2
location - VARCHAR2

Answer (score 0):

You  can use the `UNION` and `conditional aggregate` as follows:

```
SELECT TEAMNAME, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN WON = 'WON' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) WON, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN WON = 'LOST' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) LOST 
 FROM
  (SELECT G.HOME_TEAMNAME AS TEAMNAME, 
          CASE WHEN G.HOME_POINT > G.AWAY_POINT THEN 'WON' ELSE 'LOST' END AS WON -- THIS IS WINNING CONDITION
     FROM SEE_GAME G
   UNION ALL
   SELECT G.AWAY_TEAMNAME AS TEAMNAME, 
          CASE WHEN G.AWAY_POINT > G.HOME_POINT THEN 'WON'  ELSE 'LOST' END AS WON -- THIS IS WINNING CONDITION
    FROM SEE_GAME G)
GROUP BY TEAMNAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest "unpivoting" the games and then aggregating:

```
select teamname, count(*), sum(is_win), sum(is_loss)
from ((select home_teamname as teamname,
              (case when home_point > away_point then 1 else 0 end) as is_win,
              (case when home_point < away_point then 1 else 0 end) as is_loss
       from games g
      ) union all
      (select away_teamname,
              (case when home_point < away_point then 1 else 0 end) as is_win,
              (case when home_point > away_point then 1 else 0 end) as is_loss
       from games g
      )
     ) g
group by teamname;
```